# How can I apply weights to the cross-sectional dimension in a fixed effect panel model?

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have a *balanced panel* dataset in which I have observations for N countries across T quarters. I use a *fixed effect model* to explore the relationship between my variables. Since all countries have the same number of observations, they are all given the same "weight" in the regression. I would like to apply a weigthing by GDP such that observations of big countries (in terms of wealth) have more impact on my estimation. My first idea was to compute weights for all countries and rescale the dependent variable. However, I think this method will only affect the (country-specific) intercepts and won't have much impact on the coefficients. I also don't think that controlling for GDP by including it in the regression is the solution.

I am working with the R plm package to estimate my models. I know that the lm function has a weight parameter but couldn't find an equivalent in the plm package.

Any idea how I should proceed?

Comment: You could recreate the FE model with a dummy variable for each country then use lm.

Comment: There is a `weight` argument in the development version of `plm`.